# Как вызвать событие в swiper по нажатию на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper

Есть такая конструкция слайдера:

```js
var menu_obj = ['Все', 'Последние']
const ObjSlider = new Swiper('.objects-swiper', {
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination-attached',
    clickable: true,
    renderBullet: function(index, className) {
      return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (menu_obj[index]) + '</span>';
    },
  }
});
const AttachedSlider = new Swiper('.attached-swiper', {
  loop: true,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination-objects',
    type: 'fraction'
  },
  slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.objects-button-right',
    prevEl: '.objects-button-left',
  }
});
$('.objects-swiper .swiper-pagination-bullet').click(function() {
  AttachedSlider.slideTo(0, 1000, true);
})
```

```css
.objects {
  padding: 80px 0 110px 0;
  color: #141416;
}

.objects .top__container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.objects .objects__nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.objects .objects__nav .swiper-pagination-objects {
  margin: 0 27px;
  color: #141416;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.objects .objects__nav .swiper-pagination-objects .swiper-pagination-current {
  color: #EE4623;
}

.objects .objects__nav .swiper-pagination-attached {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 70px;
}

.objects .objects__nav .swiper-pagination-attached .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: initial;
  height: initial;
  opacity: initial;
  background: initial;
  border-radius: initial;
  padding: 0 35px 9px 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgba(20, 20, 22, 0.5);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(20, 20, 22, 0.2);
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.objects .objects__nav .swiper-pagination-attached .swiper-pagination-bullet:first-child {
  padding: 0 35px 9px 0;
}

.objects .objects__nav .swiper-pagination-attached .swiper-pagination-bullet:last-child {
  padding: 0 0 9px 35px;
}

.objects .objects__nav .swiper-pagination-attached .swiper-pagination-bullet:hover {
  color: #EE4623;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #EE4623;
}

.objects .objects__nav .swiper-pagination-attached .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  color: #EE4623;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #EE4623;
}

.objects .objects__nav .objects-button-left, .objects .objects__nav .objects-button-right {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.objects .objects__nav svg path {
  stroke: #141416;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="objects">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top__container">
      <div class="title__container">
        <h2 class="title">
          Объекты
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="objects__nav">
        <div class="swiper-pagination-attached"></div>
        <div class="objects-button-left">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="9.121" height="15.414" viewBox="0 0 9.121 15.414">
                                    <path id="Контур_124" data-name="Контур 124" d="M0,7,7,0l7,7" transform="translate(1.414 14.707) rotate(-90)" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2"/>
                                </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-pagination-objects"></div>
        <div class="objects-button-right">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="9.121" height="15.414" viewBox="0 0 9.121 15.414">
                                    <path id="Контур_123" data-name="Контур 123" d="M1036.165,65l7,7,7-7" transform="translate(-64.293 1050.872) rotate(-90)" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2"/>
                                </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="objects__inner">
    <div class="swiper-container objects-swiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="swiper-container attached-swiper">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                1
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                2
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                3
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="swiper-container attached-swiper">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                1
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                2
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                3
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вся проблема заключается в том, что при нажатии на кнопки "Все/Последние" нужно что-бы вложенный слайдер переключался на первый слайд. Я попытался использовать метод `swiper.slideto` из документации, выглядит это так:

```
$('.objects-swiper .swiper-pagination-bullet').click(function() {
  AttachedSlider.slideTo(0, 1000, true);
})
```

но судя по всему слушается он только внутри самого `const Swiper`, только вот функцию туда вложить не получается.
Так же у Swiper есть событие click, которое можно обрабатывать, но дело в том, что слушает он сам клик по слайдеру, а не по pagination(Кнопки переключения).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учитывая, что в вашем коде вложенные слайдеры привязаны к одному и тому `instance` - управлять ими будет невозможно. Одно из решений этой проблемы:

Создаем переменную, где будем хранить `instance` для каждого вложенного слайдера, допустим:

```
// в переменной будут храниться все созданные вложенные слайдеры
const instanceNestedSlider = {}
```

и, чтобы одной навигацией управлять разными вложенными слайдерами, создаем переменную, где будем хранить индекс текущего(видимого в настоящий момент) вложенного слайдера:

```
// индекс активного вложенного слайдера
let activeNestedSlider = 0
```

создаем функцию, которая будет создавать вложенные слайдеры по требованию

```
// функция создания нового вложенного слайдера
      const createNestedSlider = (el) => {
        return new Swiper(el, {
          loop: true,
          nested: true,
          pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination-objects',
            type: 'fraction',
          },
          slidesPerView: 3,
          spaceBetween: 30,
          // отключаем навигацию по умолчанию, так как у нас будет одна для всех
          // navigation: {
          //   nextEl: '.objects-button-right',
          //   prevEl: '.objects-button-left',
          // },
        })
      }
```

Создаем функцию, которая будет проводить управление активным вложенным слайдером посредствам пользовательской навигации:

```
// Пользовательский функционал навигации
  // так как она общая для всех вложенных слайдеров
  // берет активный слайдер и меняет слайды
  const clickNavigate = function (i) {
    if (i > 0) {
      instanceNestedSlider[activeNestedSlider].slideNext()
    } else {
      instanceNestedSlider[activeNestedSlider].slidePrev()
    }
  }
```

И используя метод [on](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#events) создаем функционал, который будет создавать вложенные слайдеры и управлять индексом активного слайдера:

```
on: {
          init: function (swiper) {
            ...
          },
          slideChange: function (swiper) {
            ...
          },
        },
```

Добавляем к элементам навигации обработчики событий:

```
...
<div class="objects-button-right" onClick="clickNavigate(1)">
...
<div class="objects-button-left" onClick="clickNavigate(-1)">
...
```

Слайдер готов к работе. В качестве наглядного пример - привожу рабочий пример:

```js
var menu_obj = ['Все', 'Последние']

// в переменной будут храниться все созданные слайдеры
const instanceNestedSlider = {}
// индекс активного вложенного слайдера
let activeNestedSlider = 0
// функция создания нового вложенного слайдера
const createNestedSlider = (el) => {
  return new Swiper(el, {
    loop: true,
    nested: true,

    observer: true,
    observeParents: true,
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination-objects',
      type: 'fraction',
    },
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    // отключаем навигацию по умолчанию, так как у нас будет одна для всех
    // navigation: {
    //   nextEl: '.objects-button-right',
    //   prevEl: '.objects-button-left',
    // },
  })
}
// Пользовательский функционал навигации
// так как она общая для всех вложенных слайдеров
// берет активный слайдер и меняет слайды
const clickNavigate = function(i) {
  if (i > 0) {
    instanceNestedSlider[activeNestedSlider].slideNext()
  } else {
    instanceNestedSlider[activeNestedSlider].slidePrev()
  }
}

const ObjSlider = new Swiper('.objects-swiper', {
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination-attached',
    clickable: true,
    observer: true,
    observeParents: true,
    renderBullet: function(index, className) {
      return (
        '<span class="' + className + '">' + menu_obj[index] + '</span>'
      )
    },
  },
  on: {
    init: function(swiper) {
      const nestedSlider =
        swiper.slides[swiper.activeIndex].querySelector(
          '.swiper-container'
        )
      // если есть вложенный контейнер слайдера
      if (nestedSlider) {
        // создаем слайдер
        instanceNestedSlider[swiper.activeIndex] =
          createNestedSlider(nestedSlider)
        // устанавливаем его активным
        activeNestedSlider = swiper.activeIndex
      }
    },
    slideChange: function(swiper) {
      // если среди созданных вложенных слайдеров нет с индексом текущего слайда
      if (!instanceNestedSlider[swiper.activeIndex]) {
        // если есть вложенный контейнер слайдера
        const nestedSlider =
          swiper.slides[swiper.activeIndex].querySelector(
            '.swiper-container'
          )
        // создаем слайдер
        instanceNestedSlider[swiper.activeIndex] =
          createNestedSlider(nestedSlider)
      } else {
        // иначе переходим к первому слайдеру в активном вложенном слайдере
        instanceNestedSlider[swiper.activeIndex].slideToLoop(
          0,
          1000,
          true
        )
        instanceNestedSlider[swiper.activeIndex].update()
        instanceNestedSlider[swiper.activeIndex].pagination.update()
      }
      // меняем индекс активного слайдера
      activeNestedSlider = swiper.activeIndex
    },
  },
})
```

```css
.objects {
  padding: 5px 0 110px 0;
  color: #141416;
}

.objects .top__container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.objects .objects__nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.objects .objects__nav .swiper-pagination-objects {
  margin: 0 27px;
  color: #141416;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.objects .objects__nav .swiper-pagination-objects .swiper-pagination-current {
  color: #EE4623;
}

.objects .objects__nav .swiper-pagination-attached {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 70px;
}

.objects .objects__nav .swiper-pagination-attached .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: initial;
  height: initial;
  opacity: initial;
  background: initial;
  border-radius: initial;
  padding: 0 35px 9px 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgba(20, 20, 22, 0.5);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(20, 20, 22, 0.2);
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.objects .objects__nav .swiper-pagination-attached .swiper-pagination-bullet:first-child {
  padding: 0 35px 9px 0;
}

.objects .objects__nav .swiper-pagination-attached .swiper-pagination-bullet:last-child {
  padding: 0 0 9px 35px;
}

.objects .objects__nav .swiper-pagination-attached .swiper-pagination-bullet:hover {
  color: #EE4623;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #EE4623;
}

.objects .objects__nav .swiper-pagination-attached .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  color: #EE4623;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #EE4623;
}

.objects .objects__nav .objects-button-left,
.objects .objects__nav .objects-button-right {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.objects .objects__nav svg path {
  stroke: #141416;
}


/* эти стили можно удалить */

.objects-swiper>.swiper-wrapper>.swiper-slide {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.objects-swiper .swiper-slide:nth-child(2) {
  background: #ddd;
}

.objects-swiper .swiper-slide .swiper-slide>div {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #ee4623;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="objects">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top__container">
      <div class="title__container">
        <h2 class="title">Объекты</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="objects__nav">
        <div class="swiper-pagination-attached"></div>
        <div class="objects-button-left" onClick="clickNavigate(-1)">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="9.121" height="15.414" viewBox="0 0 9.121 15.414">
                <path
                  id="Контур_124"
                  data-name="Контур 124"
                  d="M0,7,7,0l7,7"
                  transform="translate(1.414 14.707) rotate(-90)"
                  fill="none"
                  stroke="#fff"
                  stroke-width="2"
                />
              </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-pagination-objects"></div>
        <div class="objects-button-right" onClick="clickNavigate(1)">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="9.121" height="15.414" viewBox="0 0 9.121 15.414">
                <path
                  id="Контур_123"
                  data-name="Контур 123"
                  d="M1036.165,65l7,7,7-7"
                  transform="translate(-64.293 1050.872) rotate(-90)"
                  fill="none"
                  stroke="#fff"
                  stroke-width="2"
                />
              </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="objects__inner">
    <div class="swiper-container objects-swiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="swiper-container attached-swiper">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div>1 слайд 1 вложенного слайдера</div>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div>2 слайд 1 вложенного слайдера</div>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div>3 слайд 1 вложенного слайдера</div>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div>4 слайд 1 вложенного слайдера</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="swiper-container attached-swiper">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div>1 слайд 2 вложенного слайдера</div>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div>2 слайд 2 вложенного слайдера</div>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div>3 слайд 2 вложенного слайдера</div>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div>4 слайд 2 вложенного слайдера</div>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div>5 слайд 2 вложенного слайдера</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```